# How to make resources in maven test folder available to other projects

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have a maven projects that consists of several sub-projects.  I have three sub-projects client, server, and common.  Classes placed in the java/main folder of the common project are available to all three projects.  However classes placed in the java/test folder of the common project are not.  How do I make these classes available to all three projects?

I am working in eclipse and the code seems to compile but at run time I get class not found exceptions for any classes used in the client project that are from the common project test folder.  Classes in the common project are usable and JUnit tests in the common/test folder compile and run.

Comment: The full explanation how to do and how to use it is documented here: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/examples/create-test-jar.html

Comment: @khmarbaise: The article you posted was exactly what I was looking for.  However, I'm in a "have your cake and eat it to situation".  I would like the classes available in my Eclipse environment while I'm working but when I do the final build I would like the test classes not deployed.  I don't know that this is possible with out some further maven wrangling (e.g by making two separate maven projects: one for the development environment and one for the final released jar).

Comment: The classes we are talking about are those test classes which will be packaged into a the test-jar ? What do you mean by not being deployed ? To which target?

Answer (score 3):

The (unit) tests in src/test/ are meant to be "private" to the project itself. However you could for instance make a separate project with test base classes and such and add test dependencies.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.yours</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-test</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```